Do I need to apply for a transit visa to travel through Spain on a flight from London to Algiers if the the trip involves changing terminals?
I am an Algerian citizen and currently planning an upcoming trip that involves a layover at a Spanish airport from London.
I was wondering whether I will need to apply for a transit visa to transit through Spain?
From the website of the Spanish consulate in London, I can read that "Nationals of the following countries require a visa to transit through the international area of any airport located in the territory of the Schengen States in order to take a connecting flight to a country outside the Schengen area.
Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia and Sri Lanka.
In addition, nationals of the following countries require a visa to transit through the international area of any airport located in Spain in order to take a connecting flight to a country outside the Schengen area:
Burkina Faso, Cameroon, Chad, Côte d'Ivoire, Cuba, Djibuti, Gambia, Guinea, Guinea Bissau, Haiti, India, Liberia, Mali, Republic of the Congo, Senegal, Sierra Leone, Sudan, Syria,  Tajikistan,  Togo, Turkey, Uzbekistan y Yemen. Holders of passports issued by the Palestinian Authority also require a visa."
Accordingly, Algeria does not appear among these nations.
However, since the trip may involve changing terminals and passing through border control, I was wondering if I still need to apply for a Schengen visa. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Spain does not require Algerian citizens to have an airport transit visa for airside transit. However this map shows that Algeria is in the list of countries whose citizens need a visa to enter the Schengen area.
If your transit means you need to pass border control, you need a visa.
